# How to express Var(u/x) in terms of Bo, B1 and x in linear probability model?

Tags: econometrics

**NOTE- Pls try to use hint otherwise its fine as long as answer is correct**
Consider the following linear probability model:
yi = β0 + β1xi + ui
where yi is a binary variable that takes on values of 0 or 1 only.
**Find Var(ui|xi) in terms of β0, β1, and xi**
(Hint: I will start you off: Var(ui|xi) =Var(yi − β0 − β1xi|xi) = Var(yi|xi). So now you just need to find Var(yi|xi)!

Answer (score 0):

Since $y_i$ only takes the values $0$ and $1$, it is defined by a probability $p\in (0,1)$ of taking the value $1$. This type of random variable is said to have a Bernoulli distribution and it is denoted $y_i$ ~ $Bern(p)$.

Therefore $E(X) = p$ and its variance is:

$Var(y_i|x_i) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - (\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = p - p^2 = p(1-p)$.

Note $E(X^2)$ is also $p$, since the values it can take $\{0,1\}$ are their own squares.

Comment: It is not clear why $y_i$ ~ $Bern(p)$ implies that $E(X) = p$. Your formula for the *conditional* variance is also surprising.